# Query CMSPlugin model for draft or live objects

Tags: django-cms

I've got a CMSPlugin & a request to display it's items in another app.

Obviously for every plugin you create there is a live and draft version, so doing `audio = Audio.objects.all()` brings you duplicate instances.

How would you go about creating a query which only returns the plugin objects from public pages?

My plugin;

```
class Audio(CMSPlugin):
    """
    Model for storing audio clips.
    """
    caption = models.CharField(
        _("Title"),
        max_length=255,
        blank=True
    )
    audio_track = models.FileField()
    description = models.CharField(
        _("Description"),
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
Audio.objects.filter(placeholder__page__publisher_is_draft=False)
```

This assumes all `Audio` plugins belongs to a CMS page. CMSPlugins are not guaranteed to have a page associated with them! Unless you set `page_only` option to `True`:

```
page_only = True
```

Docs: http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/plugins.html#page-only